# How to prove that the following inequality holds?

Tags: inequality

How to prove the following inequality, if assuming $a \in (0,1)$ and $x \in (0,1)$?

$a(x-1)(x^a+1) > (x+1)(x^a -1)$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: expanding it, we get $a(x^{a+1}-x^a+x-1)>x^{a+1}+x^a-x+1$

Comment: alternate form is: $a \frac{x-1}{x+1} > \frac{x^a-1}{x^a+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $a\in(0,1)$. Let $f(t)=\tanh(at)-a\tanh(t)$ for $t\geq0$. Clearly,
$$
f'(t)=a\frac{\cosh^2(t)-\cosh^2(at)}{\cosh^2(t) \cosh^2(at)}>0,\qquad\hbox{for $t>0$}
$$
and since $f(0)=0$ we conclude that $f(t)>0$ for $t>0$. This can be written as follows
$$
\frac{1-e^{-2at}}{1+e^{-2at}}>a\frac{1-e^{-2t}}{1+e^{-2t}}\quad\hbox{for $t>0$}
$$
Now, set $x=e^{-2t}$ to obtain the desired inequality.$\qquad\square$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very elegant!